# grails redirect to another view

Tags: grails3

i am trying to create status page which check database for the job status every 5 minutes and then updates the user about the status of the job..

So once the job is finished, I want to move from the current page to result page..

To update the status i m using JavaScript :

```
function() {
            setInterval(function() {

                var uuid =" \'${uuid}\'";
                var jobid =" \'${jobid}\'";
                console.log();
                $('#checkstatus').load('/jobque/connectdatabase',{jobid:jobid,uuid:uuid});
            }, 5000);
        });
```

Checking status works correctly. I tried using redirect or forward but both these terms loads the result page into current page. I want to go to next page not load into current page ..

What are the other option available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript uses jquery to load the results of a call to a controller action into the named element.

Why not check the result of your call to the controller action and if it indicates success, then use javascript to redirect to your desired page.

controller action:

```
def checkStatus() {
    if (status_check_ok) {
            render 'url_of_page_for_redirect'
            return 
    }
    render status:409 // failure
}
```

javascript on web page:

```
$.ajax({
        timeout:5000,
        type: 'POST',
        url: controller_action_url_for_checkStatus,
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href=data
        },
        error: function(data){
            // do something else
        }
    });
```